# Deploy multiple contracts with dependencies - Truffle

Tags: solidity, truffle, testing

Say I have two contracts, an oracle and a reader.  How do I test (or even deploy) them both?

```
    contract Oracle {
        struct DocumentStruct{bytes32 name; uint value;}
        mapping(bytes32 => DocumentStruct) public documentStructs;

        function StoreDocument(bytes32 key,bytes32 name, uint value) returns (bool success) {
            documentStructs[key].value = value;
            documentStructs[key].name = name;
            return true;
        }
    }

contract Reader {
      address public oracleID;
      Oracle d;
  function Reader(address OAddress){
      d = Oracle(OAddress);
      oracleID = OAddress;
          }
 struct DocumentStruct{bytes32 name; uint value;}
  function RetrieveData(bytes32 key) public constant returns(uint) {
    DocumentStruct memory doc;
    (doc.name,doc.value) = d.documentStructs(key);
    return doc.value;
  }
    }
```

So Since the reader needs an Oracle address in the starting function, is there a way to do this in Truffle (what does the deploy_contracts.js look like?)  And how I just write tests to see if I can store documents and then read it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You deploy the Oracle, and then you have `Oracle.deployed()`.

You tell the `Reader` about Oracle with the constructor, as you have done. You tell Truffle to populate the requirement parameter in the migrations, e.g. `2_deploy_contracts.js`.

For example, something like:

```
var oracle;
Oracle.deployed()
.then(function(instance) { 
  oracle = instance; 
  deployer.deploy(Reader, oracle}); // this is where you pass it in
});
```

I'm pretty sure I flubbed the syntax on this one (I'm just going by sound), but that should give you the general idea. Main takeaway, they give you a way to pass in the constructor parameters it needs.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Awesome, just what I was looking for.  Thanks for your help.  I've seen this structure for getting addresses as well.  Is there a source that has the deployer method layed out?

Comment: In practice, I've added `function setOracle(address _oracle) onlyOwner ...` for complex systems of interlocking contracts. It just seems cleaner. `2_deploy_contracts.js` just fires them out easily/simply, and then `3_set_params.js` just does whatever is needed to send transactions to complete the initial setup.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer this syntax:

```
module.exports = function(deployer, network, accounts) {

    deployer.then(async () => {
        await deployer.deploy(A);
        await deployer.deploy(B, A.address);
        //...
    });
};
```

since it's way more readable when you have lots of contracts.

See also: https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/501#issuecomment-373886205

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `Oracle.address` directly to deploy Reader.

```
var Oracle = artifacts.require("./path/to/Oracle.sol");
var Reader = artifacts.require("./path/to/Reader.sol");

deployer.deploy(Oracle)
.then(function() {
  return deployer.deploy(Reader, Oracle.address);
});
```

Hope you'll find this useful.